# How to generate a string from a cell array

Tags: matlab

I am trying to learn MATLAB.
How can I convert this cell arraay:

```matlab
  1×4 cell array

    {'A'}    {'B4'}    {'G6'}    {'D5'}
```

to this string:

```
    A -> B4 -> G6 -> D5
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am trying to output text to the console. {'A'} {'B4'} etc. are nodes in a a* algorithm and I want to print them like this A -> B4 -> G6 -> D5

Comment: use the function `disp` or `sprintf` in a loop. Note terminology tends to be important when googling stuff about programming. You are not "replacing" anything, you are trying to output text, or "print" text to console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strjoin` to merge them into one string, with a delimeter `->`

```
c = {'A', 'B4', 'G6', 'D5'};
str = strjoin( c, ' -> ' );
disp( str );

% 'A -> B4 -> G6 -> D5'
```